# How does the "Add" method of the System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T> Work?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

**Background:** I'm trying to create my own "Vector" class to assist in performing mathematical calculations on groups of numbers.  I am overloading the arithmetic operators ( + - * / ) to achieve the functionality that I want.  At first, I used a private array in my class and then implemented the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.  Afterwards, I thought of inheriting the `List<T>` class, but after reading a couple of articles, I understand that I should use `Collection<T>` instead.  Please note that *performance is very important* when populating my "Vector" object with data.

**Question:** How does the `Collection<T>.Add()` method work?  The `List<T>.Add()` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) is very clear:

> If Count already equals Capacity, the capacity of the List is increased by automatically reallocating the internal array, and the existing elements are copied to the new array before the new element is added.

However, the `Collection<T>.Add()` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132404.aspx) says nothing at all about how it works.  When I used `List<T>` as my base class I had access to the `Capacity` property and I was able to specify the size before using the `Add()` method.  However, `Collection<T>` does not have a `Capacity` property---this is why I'm asking the question.  Again, I reiterate: performance is very important.

Since performance is an issue, perhaps I should go back to using a private array and implementing the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.  What do you think?

Comment: May I suggest not rolling your own?  see [Good library for 3D math in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607254/good-library-for-3d-math-in-c)

Comment: This might be helpful, although it doesn't cover Collection<T> directly: http://c-sharp-snippets.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/runtime-complexity-of-net-generic.html

Comment: @dtryon Thanks for the link...as you pointed out it doesn't help me with my question, but it is an excellent reference that I'll certainly use in the future.

Comment: @jonnyGold Yeah, I thought of using another library, however, I do have some other functionality that I didn't mention in my question that requires a lot of additional programming.  The algebraic operations are easy enough to implement on my own, so at this point I think that rolling my own vector class is good enough...for now. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Collection<T>` is a wrapper around `IList<T>`. The default constructor of `Collection<T>` just uses a new `List<T>`, so the `Add` behavior will be the same as `List<T>` assuming you use the default constructor.

> However, the Collection.Add() documentation says nothing at all about how it works

That's because the `Add` behavior is dependent on the underlying `IList`, which is passed in the constructor.

> However, Collection does not have a Capacity property

Again, because that would depend on what the Collection is wrapping. It wraps the *interface* `IList<T>`. The interface has no notion of capacity. There *could* be an implementation of `IList<T>` that does not have a known capacity, like records in a database.

If you need these implementation details such as capacity, then just use a `List<T>`. `Collection<T>` has no performance benefits over `List<T>` since it is using one anyway. If performance is critical to you then you may want to find a library that has already solved this problem, rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...where can I find/access the Capacity property?

Comment: +1. Note that this behavior invalidates performance expectation set in Collection.Add method...

Comment: @vcsjones Thanks for your edit.  I'm starting to agree with your suggestion of inheriting List<T> instead of Collection<T>.

Comment: I'm going to give @vcsjones the credit for answering this question; however, I very much appreciate the input form Alexei Levenkov and everyone else who commented.  I will use List<T> as my base class.

Answer (score 2):

There is no details on implementation, but there is performance characteristics for Add in the documentation:

[`List<T>.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1)

> If Count is less than Capacity, this method is an O(1) operation. If the capacity needs to be increased to accommodate the new element, this method becomes an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

[`Collection<T>.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132404.aspx) (as of 2012-06-01)

> This method is an O(1) operation.

Note that guarantee for `Collection<T>.Add` does not look right for at least collections created as wrapper on the `List<T>` or using default constructor of Collection which is implemented as Collection() : this(new List()) as @vcsjones pointed out. Looks like error in the documentation.

It should be easy to verify by measuring (which is the right way of solving performance questions) or sniffing at the sources...

Side note: You will not be able to beat List's Add performance with single array (as it is exactly what List does), you'll need to use something more complicated (like list of array chunks) to get O(1) from Add and Item[].

Comment: I appreciate your comments, especially your "side note".  However, the documentation (which you quote) is a bit confusing to me.  If the Collection<T> is wrapping a List<T>, then the Add() method cannot be an O(1) operation if it exceeds the Capacity.  Is that understanding right?

Comment: So it is confusing to me too. Definitely in case of wrapping List<T> performance of Add would be the same (O(1)/O(n) over capacity). I don't know what Collection uses when initialized without IList<T> parameter.

Comment: According to the link from tryon the LinkedList "add beyond capacity" has O(1) performance...this makes sense because (I assume) each element is dynamically created.  I don't think that Collection<T> is acting like a LinkedList (also, LinkedList doesn't implement IList).  I'm wondering if there is a mistake in the documentation.

Comment: To answer your question "What does Collection<T> use when initialized without IList<T> parameter", I've done some tests and it appears to use a List<T> object.  So, I can access the Capacity property of the underlying List<T> by doing something like: ((List<T>)base.Items)...where "base" is the Collection<T>.

Comment: @HydroPowerDeveloper agreed, the default constructor of Collection<T> is implemented as `Collection() : this(new List<T>())`.